# How to grab span text values with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer to scrape [this website](http://quotes.toscrape.com/). I want to loop over each quote and create an array of objects with 3 values each: quote, by, category. I'm having a hard time pulling the span text out of each div. Here's what I have so far:

```
        const quotes = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const grabFromDiv = (div, classname) => div 
        .querySelector(`div.${classname}`)
        .innerText 
        .trim()

        //our selectors 
        const quote_selector = 'div.quote'

        //store our data in an array of objects 
        const data = []

        //get all quotes
        const quoteDivs = document.querySelectorAll(quote_selector)

        //loop over each quote block, creating objects 
        for (const span of quoteDivs) {
            data.push({
                quote: grabFromDiv(span, 'text'),
                by: grabFromDiv(small, 'author'),
                category: grabFromDiv(a, 'tag'),
            })
        }
        //send the data back into the quotes variable
        return data 
    })
```

As of now, it is returning an array of these objects:

```
  {
     "quote": null,
     "by": null,
     "category": null
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Selectors you are using to select fields are not correct.

```
const grabFromDiv = (div, selector) => Array.from(div 
    .querySelectorAll(selector), (el => el.innerText.trim()));

for (const span of quoteDivs) {
    data.push({
        quote: grabFromDiv(span, 'span.text'),
        by: grabFromDiv(span, 'small.author'),
        category: grabFromDiv(span, 'a.tag'),
    });
}
```